# Difference between getmypid() and posix_getpid()

Tags: php

What's the difference between the `getmypid()` and the `posix_getpid()` functions?

I turned to `getmypid()` because my script has to run both on Windows and on Linux.

Answer (score 16):

It seems the main difference is what you said :

- [`getmypid`](http://php.net/getmypid) works both on windows and linux
- [`posix_getpid`](http://php.net/posix_getpid) does not work on windows, as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php)

I guess the second one exists to be kinda POSIX-compliant (if there are others POSIX functions, why not this one ? )

So, if you want your code to be portable, you'll use the first one -- as you did.